# Photoshop Scripting - user defined origin (coordinates) for a circle

Tags: javascript, coordinates, photoshop

I'm new Photoshop scripting and perhaps I'm not searching for the right terms.  I'm trying to create 3 concentric circles at a user defined location.  I have a script to create a circle but I'm not able to find a reference or snippet that will allow me to place an anchor or path or read the mouse coordinates or whatever to use as a center point for the circles.  Basically I'd like to click on an image and have the script use that location as the origin for each of the circles. Any suggestions or references on how to do this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can't find any info on this because you can't get mouse coordinates from a script. You'll have to use something else to define coordinates for your script: path points, color samplers, a selection, etc

Comment: Thanks,  I did try looking at paths and selections but didn't see anything about getting coordinates.  I'll look again. Any other key words or references I should look for?

Comment: [Scripting Reference](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/photoshop/pdfs/photoshop-javascript-ref-2020.pdf) is a good start

Comment: Btw, depending how far you want to go, maybe it's worth exploring if VB/AppleScript could help: I imagine those coukd be used to get mouse coords but also imagine using those will make the task more difficult

Comment: ...as for keywords, check `PathItem` and `Document.selection` in the docs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Color Sampler tool provided the most direct way to create a user defined reference point for my application.

```
    var colorsamplerRef=app.activeDocument.colorSamplers[0];
    var currentPos= colorsamplerRef.position;
   
    var x = currentPos[0];
    var y = currentPos[1];
```

Comment: @PySyemya, if you are going down that road don't forget to add `app.activeDocument.colorSamplers.removeAll();` to remove samples afterwards. Which has a maximum of 10.